# Add a css class for Ajax Action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-ajax

How I can add a class for Ajax.ActionLink?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove this photo","RemovePhoto","Admin",new{Id=Model.filename, @class="ActionClass"},new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "RemoveSuccess"})
```

but this method don't create css class for this ActionLink.
My class is added to the url:
AdminTools/RemovePhoto/ffff.JPG?class=RemovePhoto

Comment: Hi SirRoland. Did my answer help to solve your problem. If so, please can you mark it as accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `(AjaxHelper, String, String, Object, AjaxOptions, Object)` method signature for this.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

As you can see, the final parameter is a collection of HTML attributes.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470546.aspx

Comment: Since `class` is a reserved keyword you'll need to use `@class` as the key.  So your last parameter might look something like this: `new { @class = "magic" }`

Answer (score 5):

Should be use like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove this photo","RemovePhoto","Admin",new{Id=Model.filename          },new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "RemoveSuccess"} , new {@class="Action Class"})
```